# Loop PHP array based in first array

Tags: php, arrays

I just found out how to loop an array based on another array, but my problem is that if the second array is just 1 object than it works fine but I want to make it work with two objects.

Here is an example how it do works,

```
$shorten = array(
  0 => 'ECAR',
  1 => 'CCAR',
  2 => 'ICAR',
  3 => 'SCAR',
  4 => 'FCAR',
  5 => 'PCAR',
);

$data = array(
  'Hertz' => array(
        'ECAR' => '49.21',
        'CCAR' => '71.04',
        'ICAR' => '89.58',
        'SCAR' => '100.00',
    )
  ),
  'Avis' => array(
        'ECAR' => '412.00',
        'CCAR' => '347.00',
        'ICAR' => '285.00',
        'SCAR' => '224.00',
        'FCAR' => '165.00',
        'PCAR' => '100.00',
    )
  ),
);

// default array as the base
$shorten = array_combine($shorten, array_fill(0, count($shorten), 'n/a'));

foreach($data as &$array) {
    // merge to get set members
    $array = array_merge($shorten, $array);
}
unset($array);

print_r($data);
```

But I want to make it work with this one,

```
$shorten = array(
  0 => 'ECAR',
  1 => 'CCAR',
  2 => 'ICAR',
  3 => 'SCAR',
  4 => 'FCAR',
  5 => 'PCAR',
);

$data = array(
  'Hertz' => array(
    'NYCT01' => array(
        'ECAR' => '49.21',
        'CCAR' => '71.04',
        'ICAR' => '89.58',
        'SCAR' => '100.00',
    )
  ),
  'Avis' => array(
    'NYCT01' => array(
        'ECAR' => '412.00',
        'CCAR' => '347.00',
        'ICAR' => '285.00',
        'SCAR' => '224.00',
        'FCAR' => '165.00',
        'PCAR' => '100.00',
    )
  ),
);

// default array as the base
$shorten = array_combine($shorten, array_fill(0, count($shorten), 'n/a'));

foreach($data as $firstArray) {
    foreach($firstArray as &$array){
        // merge to get set members
        $array = array_merge($shorten, $array);
    }
}
unset($array);

print_r($data);
```

And this is what I want it to be,

```
Array
(
    [Hertz] => Array
        (
            [ECAR] => 49.21
            [CCAR] => 71.04
            [ICAR] => 89.58
            [SCAR] => 100.00
            [FCAR] => n/a
            [PCAR] => n/a
        )

    [Avis] => Array
        (
            [ECAR] => 412.00
            [CCAR] => 347.00
            [ICAR] => 285.00
            [SCAR] => 224.00
            [FCAR] => 165.00
            [PCAR] => 100.00
        )

)
```

Comment: $data[1][0][0] = 412.00; this is how your would access array in array in array etc. if thats what you meant, is it? I do not really understand your question.

Comment: Please check the array what I want it should be, thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($data AS $company => $nyc){
    $inner = $nyc['NYCT01'];
    foreach($shorten AS $car){
        if(array_key_exists($car, $inner)){
            $output[$company][$car] = $inner[$car];
        }else {
            $output[$company][$car] = "n/a";
        }
    }
}
```

Just loop through the data and check if the key of any of the cars exists inside the NYCT01 array, if it does set the value, else, "n/a".

My output:

```
Array
(
    [Hertz] => Array
        (
            [ECAR] => 49.21
            [CCAR] => 71.04
            [ICAR] => 89.58
            [SCAR] => 100.00
            [FCAR] => n/a
            [PCAR] => n/a
        )

    [Avis] => Array
        (
            [ECAR] => 412.00
            [CCAR] => 347.00
            [ICAR] => 285.00
            [SCAR] => 224.00
            [FCAR] => 165.00
            [PCAR] => 100.00
        )

)
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but my problem is that the `$inner` is different in my array, I mean it might be for example `NYCT02` or `NYCC01` etc.

Comment: Then alternatively you could loop through $nyc

Comment: Yes you're right, I'm trying to do that, I'm struggling a little here, hope to figure it out.

Comment: Thank you Marcus I got it work, please see the answer I entered,

Comment: No problem! Mark the question as answered then.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it work this is the real code I figured,

```
foreach($data as $company => $nyc){
    foreach($nyc as $inner => $s){
        foreach($shorten as $car){
            if(array_key_exists($car, $nyc[$inner])){
                $output[$company][$car] = $nyc[$inner][$car];
            }else {
                $output[$company][$car] = "n/a";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks so much for your help Marcus,

Good luck.